# Can't Install npm, Can't Remove npm, Can't Access Any Commands, Can't Install Coffeescript

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, node.js

I am on Mac OS X Lion, I just used the package installer from nodejs.org to install node.js. Node.js is working fine, and Node.js comes with npm. I have homebrew installed as well. I am just trying to install coffeescript, but the terminal keeps throwing an error. So i decieded to check what version of npm I am running. It just keeps throwing an error. Whenever i try to use any npm command, it throws the same error. I tried to just install npm seperately and I get and error, and same thing when i try to remove npm. Can anyone please help, this is so unbelievably frustrating.

**Error when i call npm help**

```
macbook-air:~ mcbeav$ sudo npm help

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: No such module
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/config-defs.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/ini.js:43:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
macbook-air:~ mcbeav$
```

**error when i try to install npm through the terminal**

```
All clean!

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chmod '/usr/local/bin/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! message EPERM, chmod '/usr/local/bin/npm'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
npm ERR! error rolling back npm@1.1.21 Error: EPERM, chmod '/usr/local/bin/npm'

npm ERR! Error: EPERM, chmod '/usr/local/bin/npm'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.3.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! cwd /private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.17
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! message EPERM, chmod '/usr/local/bin/npm'
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/g1/tn_gpxcj423d1dn_jx2g9gp40000gn/T/npm.1064/package/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
It failed
macbook-air:~ mcbeav$
```

Error when i try to remove npm

```
macbook-air:~ mcbeav$ sudo npm uninstall npm -g

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
    Error: No such module
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/config-defs.js:5:21)
        at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
        at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
        at require (module.js:370:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/ini.js:43:18)
        at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    macbook-air:~ mcbeav$
```

Comment: Have you tried the chmod from an actual root shell?

Comment: to be honest, I am not extremely familiar with the terminal, so no. any chance you might be able to give me a little guidance?

Comment: It should be possible to activate a true root account (for heavens sake put a good password on it!) on Mac OSX by executing "sudo passwd root", which should the allow you to "su -". YMMV on Lion, and care is advised using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out an old installation was conflicting with the new one. The old was stored in

```
usr/bin
```

where the new was stored in

```
usr/local/bin
```

i had to install it using the command

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo clean=yes sh
```

and it worked fine, for anyone else having the same issue, very frustrating

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, but doing a clean install doesn't seem to help and it still looking for nmp in usr/bin. I tried a `hash -r` hearing that that might help, but still no luck. Any other advice on how I might clear out that old npm?